# How to dockerize next.js production image with prisma

Tags: postgresql, docker, next.js, docker-compose, prisma

next.js build process needs database for SSG but docker images during the build can't access outside world like host machine localhost (if I expose 5432 port) or running containers by service name through docker network (only containers can communicate).

```
POSTGRES_HOST=   # localhost | db-stage
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password@$POSTGRES_HOST:5432/my-database?schema=public
```

following [nemanjam/nextjs-prisma-boilerplate](https://github.com/nemanjam/nextjs-prisma-boilerplate) guide I tried to integrate traefik proxy through external network but no luck.

I wait for postgres to be ready inside its container before proceeding.

I suspect the answer is in mounting postgres data in prisma folder so that it can be accessed from the image when coping ./prisma, but I think it is not possible to run the db inside the image

```yaml
services:
  db-stage:
    volumes:
      - ./prisma/pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/data-stage
```

the easiest workaround is to build during ENTRYPOINT with

```bash
npm run build && npm start
```

but it is far from ideal as node_modules would contain devDeps... like dev container